# Awesomium многопоточность

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, awesomium

Работаю с Telegram APi от Mr.Round Robin и Awesomium. В моей работе надо сделать скрин шот сайта. Делаю я это через Awesomium.

```
var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);
{
  webView.Invoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    webView.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");
    while (webView.IsLoading)
    {
       WebCore.Update();
    }
    BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webView.Surface;
    surface.SaveToPNG("Screenshot.png", true);
    webView.Dispose();
  }), new object[] { });
}
```

Но при повторном использовании функции вылетает Exception на `var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);`.

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

Это вероятно связанно, что библиотека Telegram работает с многопоточностью. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Также вопрос #2. Временами дает Exception на `WebCore.Update();` мол вышло за пределы границы. Как решить

P.S Приложение консольное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что `WebCore` предназначено для работы только в одном потоке.

В вашем случае вам надо явно создать этот поток:

```
new Thread(() => WebCore.Run()) {
    Name = "Awesomium control thread",
    IsBackground = true,
}.Start();
```

Любую работу с Awesomium надо передавать в этот поток:

```
WebCore.QueueWork(() => {
    var webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080);
    webView.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");

    // ...
});
```

Отмечу, что крутить цикл в ожидании загрузки означает убить всю многопоточность. Надо подписываться на события:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

WebCore.QueueWork(async () => {
    using(webView = WebCore.CreateWebView(1920, 1080)) {
        webView.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");
        webView.LoadingFrameComplete += (o, e) => {
            if (!webView.IsLoading) tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        };
        webView.LoadingFrameFailed += (o, e) => {
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(e.ErrorDescription));
        };
        await tcs.Task;
    }
});

// теперь чтобы дождаться окончания загрузки страницы можно использовать await tcs.Task или tcs.Task.Wait();
```

Comment: А обязательно оперировать низкоуровневыми Thread? Не проще ли делать это в Task'e?

Comment: @iluxa1810 WebCore требует для своей работы выделенного потока. В чем смысл использовать Task для создания потока?

Comment: Спасибо, ошибку не выдает. Но теперь после `await tcs.Task;` пишу `BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)webView.Surface;
                    surface.SaveToPNG("Screenshot.png", true);
                    webView.Dispose();`  и он ее не генерирует =(

Comment: @Nikita ставьте точку останова и отлаживайте. Я с Awesomium толком не работал, мог напутать что-нибудь с событиями.